# How many interfaces can a Java class have?

Tags: java

I know that a Java class can have one parent class (`extends`) and implement some interfaces (`implements`). Is there a limit in the number of interfaces that a class can implement?

Comment: In English please

Comment: Pleas use English or write your questione here [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: would vote to close this question

Answer (score 2):

I redirect you here and the answer of @Jivings:

[How much interfaces a class file can implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034035/how-much-interfaces-a-class-file-can-implement)

> From the Java VM Specification on Limitations of the JVM:
>
> > The number of direct superinterfaces of a class or interface is limited to 65535 by the size of the interfaces_count item of the ClassFile structure.
>
> That is the only limitation. And it is due to the structure of the compiled Java bytecode.
>
> shareeditflag
>
> edited Jul 30 '16 at 16:55
>
> Laurel
>   4,57992136
>
> answered Jun 14 '12 at 13:28
>
> Jivings
>   18.5k44283