# How many interfaces can extends interface in java?

Tags: java, jvm

Good day!

I know that class implements 65535 interfaces (JVM limit), what about interface? How many interfaces can extends interface in java? The same value or not?

Thanks :)

Comment: Possibly this answer - specific for interface extensions -  which is same value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034141/2711811

Comment: The number of interfaces a class implements *directly* is limited to 65535. Likewise, the number of interfaces an interface extends *directly* is limited to 65535. Since this limit is imposed by the class file format, it doesn’t matter whether you’re talking about a class implementing interfaces or an interface extending interfaces, as this doesn’t make a difference to the class file format either.